# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' while launching the Django App

Tags: python, django

while running the command >python manage.py runserver to launch the app

getting the below error, is there any package needs to be updated??

```
File "D:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 201, in get_connection_params
if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: You did not specify the `HOST` variable in the `settings.py` of the database.

Comment: it set has below , what should i I give if i am running it from my local                                                                                          
       HOST': os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
        'PORT': '3306'

Comment: then there is no `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable, since if the variable does not exists, `None` is used.

Answer (score 2):

You did not set a value for `HOST` in the:

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'my_db_name',
        'USER': 'my_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': 'name_of_the_host',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

If you use an environment variable, the environment variable needs to be defined, so if you use:

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'my_db_name',
        'USER': 'my_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

then the `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable should be defined. It is is not, `os.getenv` will return `None`, hence the error.

Comment: it set has below , what should i I give if i am running it from my local HOST': os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST'), 'PORT': '3306

Comment: then there is no `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable, since if the variable does not exists, `None` is used..